# Is it possible to create a UI in AWS that is only accessible when logged in through the console?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to create a Javascript React UI that is only accessible from within the AWS console?

Maybe an S3 hosted static site only viewable with an active console session somehow?

What options do I have? I've had a Google and can't see much - it seems like an unusual request.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Typically you would use Cognito, SAML 2.0, OpenID Connect etc. Example of React app using Amplify with login via Google or Facebook [here](https://www.prplbx.com/resources/blog/social-login-with-aws-amplify-guide/).